# Where is a missing point of "$"?

Tags: pdftex

My Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a0paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{diagbox,array}

\newlength{\setsize}

\begin{document}
\settowidth{\setsize}{$\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{x}\pm\sqrt{y}}{z}$}
\newcommand{\setstruct}{\vphantom{$\left|\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr0.5\setsize+\tabcolsep}\right.$}}
\newcommand{\setlabel}{\diagbox[dir=NE]{$\theta_1$}{$\theta_2$}}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c||*{17}{>{\setstruct$\displaystyle}w{c}{\setsize}<{$}|}}
        \hline
        \setlabel         & 0                   & $\frac{\pi}{6}$              & $\frac{\pi}{4}$              & $\frac{\pi}{3}$              & $\frac{\pi}{2}$     & $\frac{2}{3}\pi$             & $\frac{3}{4}\pi$             & $\frac{5}{6}\pi$             & $\pi$               & $\frac{7}{6}\pi$             & $\frac{5}{4}\pi$             & $\frac{4}{3}\pi$             & $\frac{3}{2}\pi$    & $\frac{5}{3}\pi$             & $\frac{7}{4}\pi$             & $\frac{11}{6}\pi$            & $2\pi$              \\
        \hline \hline
        0                 & -1                  & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{1}{2}                 & 0                   & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & 1                   & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{1}{2}                  & 0                   & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -1                  \\
        \hline
        $\frac{\pi}{6}$   & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{1}{2}         & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{1}{2}        & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
        \hline
        $\frac{\pi}{4}$   & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        \hline
        $\frac{\pi}{3}$   & -\frac{1}{2}        & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{2}         & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{2}        \\
        \hline
        $\frac{\pi}{2}$   & 0                   & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & 1                   & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{1}{2}                  & 0                   & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -1                  & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{1}{2}                 & 0                   \\
        \hline
        $\frac{2}{3}\pi$  & \frac{1}{2}         & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{1}{2}        & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{1}{2}         \\
        \hline
        $\frac{3}{4}\pi$  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
        \hline
        $\frac{5}{6}\pi$  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{2}         & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{2}        & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \\
        \hline
        $\pi$             & 1                   & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{1}{2}                  & 0                   & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -1                  & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{1}{2}                 & 0                   & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & 1                   \\
        \hline
        $\frac{7}{6}\pi$  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{1}{2}        & -\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}          & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{1}{2}         & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \\
        \hline
        $\frac{5}{4}\pi$  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
        \hline
        $\frac{4}{3}\pi$  & \frac{1}{2}         & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{2}        & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{2}         \\
        \hline
        $\frac{3}{2}\pi$  & 0                   & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -1                  & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{1}{2}                 & 0                   & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & 1                   & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{1}{2}                  & 0                   \\
        \hline
        $\frac{5}{3}\pi$  & -\frac{1}{2}        & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{1}{2}         & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{1}{2}        \\
        \hline
        $\frac{7}{4}\pi$  & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        \hline
        $\frac{11}{6}\pi$ & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{2}        & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{2}         & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
        \hline
        $2\pi$            & -1                  & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{1}{2}                 & 0                   & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & 1                   & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{1}{2}                  & 0                   & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -1                  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.18 ...    & 0                   & $\frac{\pi}{6}
                                                  $              & $\frac{\p...
```

Where is a missing point?? I cannot find it...

Comment: The above isn't a comprete code...

Comment: You're adding `$` at the start end end of all the cells in your tabular header (`>{\setstruct$...`). Either don't do that, or don't use `$ ... $` in any of the cells.

Comment: At first, I wrote circular measure, but I changed into ragian. If I continue ragian, where code should I rewrite?

Comment: Ragian? You mean radians?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're adding `$` at the start and end of all cells (except for the first column) via the tabular header, i.e. `>{\setstruct$\displaystyle}w{c}{\setsize}<{$}|}`. When you do that, you cannot use `$ \frac{a}{b} $` in those columns, I guess the first `$` then switches back out of math mode, and the `\frac` is in text mode.

You just need to remove all the `$` from the first row of your table, then it works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a0paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{diagbox,array}

\newlength{\setsize}

\begin{document}
\settowidth{\setsize}{$\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{x}\pm\sqrt{y}}{z}$}
\newcommand{\setstruct}{\vphantom{$\left|\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr0.5\setsize+\tabcolsep}\right.$}}
\newcommand{\setlabel}{\diagbox[dir=NE]{$\theta_1$}{$\theta_2$}}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c||*{17}{>{\setstruct$\displaystyle}w{c}{\setsize}<{$}|}}
        \hline
        \setlabel         & 0                   & \frac{\pi}{6}              & \frac{\pi}{4}              & \frac{\pi}{3}              & \frac{\pi}{2}     & \frac{2}{3}\pi             & \frac{3}{4}\pi             & \frac{5}{6}\pi             & \pi               & \frac{7}{6}\pi             & \frac{5}{4}\pi             & \frac{4}{3}\pi             & \frac{3}{2}\pi    & \frac{5}{3}\pi             & \frac{7}{4}\pi             & \frac{11}{6}\pi            & 2\pi              \\
        \hline \hline
        0                 & -1                  & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{1}{2}                 & 0                   & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & 1                   & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{1}{2}                  & 0                   & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -1                  \\
        \hline
        $\frac{\pi}{6}$   & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{1}{2}         & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{1}{2}        & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
        \hline
        $\frac{\pi}{4}$   & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        \hline
        $\frac{\pi}{3}$   & -\frac{1}{2}        & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{2}         & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{2}        \\
        \hline
        $\frac{\pi}{2}$   & 0                   & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & 1                   & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{1}{2}                  & 0                   & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -1                  & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{1}{2}                 & 0                   \\
        \hline
        $\frac{2}{3}\pi$  & \frac{1}{2}         & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{1}{2}        & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{1}{2}         \\
        \hline
        $\frac{3}{4}\pi$  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
        \hline
        $\frac{5}{6}\pi$  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{2}         & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{2}        & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \\
        \hline
        $\pi$             & 1                   & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{1}{2}                  & 0                   & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -1                  & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{1}{2}                 & 0                   & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & 1                   \\
        \hline
        $\frac{7}{6}\pi$  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{1}{2}        & -\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}          & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{1}{2}         & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \\
        \hline
        $\frac{5}{4}\pi$  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
        \hline
        $\frac{4}{3}\pi$  & \frac{1}{2}         & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{2}        & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{2}         \\
        \hline
        $\frac{3}{2}\pi$  & 0                   & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -1                  & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{1}{2}                 & 0                   & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & 1                   & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{1}{2}                  & 0                   \\
        \hline
        $\frac{5}{3}\pi$  & -\frac{1}{2}        & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{1}{2}         & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{1}{2}        \\
        \hline
        $\frac{7}{4}\pi$  & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        \hline
        $\frac{11}{6}\pi$ & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -1                           & -\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{2}        & 0                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & 1                            & \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{2}         & 0                            & -\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
        \hline
        $2\pi$            & -1                  & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{1}{2}                 & 0                   & \frac{1}{2}                  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & 1                   & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}           & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}           & \frac{1}{2}                  & 0                   & -\frac{1}{2}                 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}          & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}          & -1                  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```